# NSURLRequest: Does it implicitly delete cookies?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cookies, nsurlrequest

Here's a really simple question. I just ran into an error where I needed to clear a cookie manually.

What happened was, I'm using the GTMOAuth2 library for authentication. This library presents a web-view to collect user credentials. And then all subsequent requests are done via regular HTTP, where we add the received oauth token into the header.

My colleague working on the back-end told me that one of these subsequent non-UIWebView requests asks me to clear the header. Of course for the web-client this would just work, but not on mobile.

For HTTP, I'm using the nice light-weight [BBHTTP](https://github.com/brunodecarvalho/BBHTTP) library - a little objective-C wrapper for cURL. So this got me thinking: Do regular, vanila NSURLRequests have seam-less Cookie integration, or would I have the same behvior where I need to clear the cookie manually there too?

Comment: I think it should work without having to add anything. You may inspect [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies] at different points so you can sure it all works.

Comment: OK, I'll log an issue about this with BBHTTP then. Thanks.